# LoadCursor and Mixed DPI Multiple Monitors

Tags: windows, winapi, hidpi

When the `LoadCursor` function is used to load a cursor from a resource, the resulting `HCURSOR` can be used across different monitors and always appears at the correct size.

ie: typically:

- on a 96 dpi monitor the 32x32 resource is used,
- on a 192 dpi monitor the 64x64 resource is used.

However, when a cursor is programmatically created from memory (say using `LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx` and `CreateIconFromResourceEx`) the resulting cursor has a fixed resolution.  This means it appears at the wrong size on at least one monitor in a mixed DPI multi-monitor setup.

I also checked out the `LoadCursorFromFile` and it too provides this dynamic resolution behaviour like `LoadCursor`.

Is there a way to programmatically create a cursor that dynamically switches depending which monitor it's shown on?  What magic is going on behind the scenes for cursors loaded with `LoadCursor` to work differently?

Answer (score 3):

After much experimentation I finally discovered that WPF can load cursors from resource and memory streams and get the correct DPI behaviour if the `scaleWithDpi` option is used:

```cs
public Cursor(Stream cursorStream, bool scaleWithDpi)
```

Looking at the reference source it ends up in the function `LoadFromStream` which loads the stream by writing it to a temporary file and the loading from the file.  [See source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/system/windows/Input/Cursor.cs,322)

To sum up:

- It seems the only way to get a dynamic DPI cursor like this is with the Win32 native resource loading functions and by loading from a file.  It doesn't seem like you can load a cursor directly from memory with this behavior.
- The "dynamic dpi" part of this behavior seems to be related to the `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` flag passed to the `LoadImage` function.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new API as of Windows 10 1607 that might help: [SetThreadCursorCreationScaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreadcursorcreationscaling)

Comment: Nice... that certainly looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

> What magic is going on behind the scenes for cursors loaded with LoadCursor to work differently?

[LoadImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew) with provided `hInst`/`MAKEINTRESOURCE(resId)` or `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag and [LoadCursorFromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorfromfilew) APIs are indeed saving additional information in returned `HCURSOR`/`HICON`.

[DrawIconEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawiconex) with `DI_DEFAULTSIZE` and [CopyImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-copyimage) with `LR_COPYFROMRESOURCE` and maybe other APIs are using this information to get best fit icon image from resource source for DPI-dependant size for current monitor/window.

This icon source information can be acquired manually with [GetIconInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-geticoninfoexw) in `szModName`/`wResID`/`szResName` member of `ICONINFOEX` structure that is available since Windows Vista.

[CreateIconFromResourceEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createiconfromresourceex) does not set this info since it just receives memory pointer to the icon/cursor bits. In this case simple image scaling is applied on `DrawIconEx` call.

It seems there is no other way to use this DPI-aware draw mechanism other than to use a load from file/exe/dll.

Some info on this topic in Raymond Chen blog:

- [Icons and cursors know where they came from](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080820-00/?p=21173)
- [Why is my icon being drawn at the wrong size when I call DrawIcon?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100729-00/?p=13293)
- [Why does the DrawIcon function draw at the default icon size?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120216-00/?p=8293)

PS: **As a workaround** I think it is possible to handle [WM_SETCURSOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor) window message, calculate a DPI-aware cursor size for your window (use `wParam` with [GetDpiForWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdpiforwindow) and [GetSystemMetricsForDpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetricsfordpi) with `SM_CXCURSOR`/`SM_CYCURSOR`) load corresponding `HCURSOR` and call [SetCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor) function with it.

Also there is a new user cursor size setting in Windows 10 that may be accounted too. It is saved in `CursorBaseSize` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors` registry. [Here is some Qt code](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowscursor.cpp#L660-L677) that deals with it and returns proper cursor size.

Comment: Here is the list of recommended cursor sizes for different monitor DPIs: https://www.tenforums.com/customization/40973-custom-cursors.html#post569584