# Capture Windows cursor HighDPI

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, win32gui, mouse-cursor

I wonder how I can correctly capture the mouse cursor when having a primary screen FullHD and a second screen 4K?

When the cursor is over the FullHD screen, I call `DrawIconEx(hdcDest, 0, 0, cursorHandle, 32, 32, NULL, DI_NORMAL);`, and the result is nice.

When the cursor is over the 4K screen, I call `DrawIconEx(hdcDest, 0, 0, cursorHandle, 48, 48, NULL, DI_NORMAL);`, but the result is blurred, not as smooth as displayed on the screen.

My actual C# code:

```
var hdcSrc = NativeMethods.GetWindowDC(IntPtr.Zero);
var bitmap = new Drawing.Bitmap(48, 48, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);                            using (var g = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
  var hdcDest = g.GetHdc();
  NativeMethods.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, BitBltRop.SRCCOPY | BitBltRop.CAPTUREBLT);
  NativeMethods.DrawIconEx(hdcDest, 0, 0, this.cursorHandle, 48, 48, 0, IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.DI_NORMAL);
  g.ReleaseHdc();
}
```

What I get at 48x48:

Blurred cursor

[image: 1]

what I want to get at 48x48:

Smooth cursor

[image: 2]

Does someone know how we must exactly capture the mouse cursor under Windows 11, according to the Per Monitor DPI feature?

Comment: Are you manifested per-monitor DPI aware?

Comment: Yes. But anyway, any solutions would be good to me.

Comment: Cursor handle should contain additional info about cursor resource. Also, you have to use LR_DEFAULTSIZE flag when drawing. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76505826/1795050

Comment: Another option: you can try to use CopyImage with LR_COPYFROMRESOURCE flag.